# Amazon page redirecting to payment page on my wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, security

When I open an Amazon page on my apple devices, it automatically redirects to a login page, and then next to the payment page if I enter dummy login credentials. This happens only on my wi-fi. This does not happen with non-Apple devices on my wi-fi network. This also does not happen with the devices on another network.

Recently, I found that I am not able to open discussions.apple.com. It says server not found. But, when I change the wi-fi it opens fine. 
Any suggestions will be helpful.

My router password and username was set to default. I changed my default password. I also went ahead and changed my wifi passwords. Still, no progress.

Comment: What payment page is this? Please give the URL.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Prime-One-Year-Membership/dp/B00DBYBNEE

Comment: Are you using Safari?

Comment: It is not redirecting to a particular URL. The page content redirects to login page and once I enter dummy login credentials, it redirected to this url.   http://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Prime-One-Year-Membership/dp/1.php

Comment: Yes, I am using Safari. I am having similar issue with Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in my network page that my DNS setting is compromised. It was set manually to an IP address. I changed it to automatic. Now, it is working fine.

Comment: Whatever changed it could change it again. Only sure solution: full reinstall.

Comment: What re-install are you talking about? Can you please be more specific.

Comment: The OS.  Malware removal is not always complete. Never use any of the devices whose setting were compromised again until you completely wiped it and reinstalled the OS. This because you may have simply cured one of the symptoms, but not the root cause which made it vulnerable. And many worms change lots of settings, finding and corecting all of them is very hard. The only sure solution is a new clean start of the OS, updates, virus scanner, and only then restore data from backups.

Comment: Would have linked to this if it was a windows PC, but the idea is the same: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit/157533#157533

Comment: I have about 4 devices (laptop, phones and tablet included) connecting to the same router. All 6 devices encountered this problem. Do you suggest the sure shot way to be safe is to re-install OS in all the 6 devices? I probably should get an anti-virus for apple devices as well. I never thought, I need anti-virus for apple devices. (I am not an apple fan-boi)

Comment: Yes and no. If all run the same OS then consider a clean install on whatever device you use for internet banking, amazon etc. But first check the router. Was (or is!) its admin page open from the Internet side. Does it hand out DNS? Does it hand out your providers DNS or 8.8.8.8 or something 'strange'.